# django admin site customization change_list.html

Tags: django

Is it possible to change the viewi of change_list in Django admin site?
just like on the picture
[image]
this is my model.py

```
class gradingPeriod(models.Model):
    Grade_Scales_Setting= models.ForeignKey(gradeScalesSetting, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField()
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request,blank=True)
    StartDate=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    EndDate=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

class gradingPeriodsSetting(models.Model):
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                                         null=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    NumberOfGradingPeriods = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class gradingPeriodsSummary(models.Model):
    Grading_Periods_Setting= models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriodsSetting, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField()
    Start_Grading_Period= models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    End_Grading_Period= models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

I don't know how to code it on the admin.py what I desire design in my change_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit yout admin.py file changing the change_list_template attribute.

For example:

```
class MyFirstobjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = path.to.my.custom.view.function
```

You can see more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/

**EDIT**
adding sample with your models

```
@admin.register(gradingPeriod)
class gradingPeriodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'myapp/mymodel_change_list.html'

@admin.register(gradingPeriodsSetting)
class gradingPeriodsSettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'myapp/mymodel_change_list.html'

@admin.register(gradingPeriodsSummary)    
class gradingPeriodsSummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'myapp/mymodel_change_list.html'
```

Comment: ahm can you be more specific?

Comment: or can you give me an example that appropriate to my models.py, please sir

Comment: I got this error sir myapp/mymodel_change_list.html

Comment: This is a path to a file in yout project structure. The file exists?

Comment: the template  change_list.html locates in the Hompage/template/Homepage/change_list.html, I receive this error Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin\\/(?P<app_label>Homepage|auth)/$']